# Why does KIF UIView:dragFromPoint:toPoint not result in touchesEnded:withEvent being called on my view?

Tags: ios, acceptance-testing, kif-framework

This question is about the iOS acceptance testing framework KIF.

I have a test step which uses the KIF extension to `UIView dragFromPoint:toPoint`.  I have a custom view class which implements `touchesBegan`/`touchesMoved`/`touchesEnded`/`touchesCancelled`.

From my KIF test step I convert my coordinates to that of my custom view and call `dragFromPoint`.  `NSLog` & breakpoints tell me that `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` are being called on my view but `touchesEnded` is not.  Looking at the KIF code I can see that it's posting this event but I can't figure out why it's not being delivered to my view when the other two are.

Here is an excerpt of my KIF test step code:

```
// Convert points to coordinate system of the CoinView
CGPoint coinCenter = [view convertPoint:view.center fromView:view.superview];
CGPoint coinTarget = [view convertPoint:coinSlotTarget fromView:coinSlotView.superview];
[view dragFromPoint:coinCenter toPoint:coinTarget];
```

Comment: any further findings on this? I encounter same issue here

Comment: I explicitly called the touchesBegin, dragged and touchUp inside category function and it worked as I expected. May be a pull request might solve this. Will stress test my implementation. Please watch my fork for more update on this, https://github.com/krutarth/KIF

Comment: i have similar kind of situation, in my case there is another view in the view hierarchy with tap gesture which is interfacing the touchesEnded delegate method

Comment: this is several years too late most likely, but is the `coinTarget` point still within the bounds of the `view`? Perhaps that view isn't get a `touchesEnded` callback since the touch is ending outside it's view bounds?